# Operator '==' has no left operand

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

Given:

```
#if defined(TESTING) 
   #if (TESTING == UNIT_TEST)
            State<StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum>::_isIgnoredEvent = false;
            State<StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum>::_isInvalidEvent = false;
   #endif
#endif
```

where `TESTING` is defined, as is `UNIT_TEST`, and `TESTING == UNIT_TEST`, why is GCC saying

```
../testing/fsm/../../fsm/h/state.h:207:17: error: operator '==' has no left operand
    #if (TESTING == UNIT_TEST)
                 ^
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682a5d097ee342f4)

Comment: How do you defined `TESTING` ?

Comment: After all this time, suddenly three downvotes. If anyone will tell me why, I will correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that you've merely defined TESTING without defining it with a value, either inline, or as part of the compiler command line.

```
#define TESTING
```

It is defined, and #if defined tests true, but comparison won't work because its macro replacement value is nothing (or the wrong type).

If you give it a value, however, then your code works.

```
#define TESTING 1
#define UNIT_TEST 1

#if defined(TESTING) 
#if (TESTING == UNIT_TEST)
cout << "Unit test";
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: True answer. Please note that compilers vary in how they handle command line definition of symbols. Was this how the symbol was defined, and if so which compiler is this?

Comment: @david.pfx did you mean to comment on the OP's question, or my answer?

Comment: Both. Just lazy I guess. You could update your answer to include the possibility that the symbol was defined on the command line, and the OP could say whether it was or not.

Comment: @david.pfx I already included that possibility in my original answer.

Comment: I defined it in the NetBeans project file, which, I presume, means that it will be passed on the command line.